# RDP Connection with custom scaling (High DPI)

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, high-dpi

I've two computer both running Windows 10 (1909).

PC 1 has a 4k 27" screen and I've set custom scaling to 160 %. When I open a RDP connection to PC 2 it has set the same scaling for the RDP connection, as well to 160 %. But since last Friday it sets the scaling to 150 %. I've no idea why?

Then I tried the following settings:

```
PC 1 160 % --> RDP PC 2 150 % <-- last week this was 160 %
PC 1 100 % --> RDP PC 2 100 %
PC 1 125 % --> RDP PC 2 125 %
PC 1 150 % --> RDP PC 2 150 %
PC 1 170 % --> RDP PC 2 175 % <-- last week this was 170 %
PC 1 175 % --> RDP PC 2 175 % 
PC 1 200 % --> RDP PC 2 200 %
```

I can't find any setting for the DPI value of an RDP connection, see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/rdp-files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I set the custom scaling as well to 160 % on PC2 and I set the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\IgnoreClientDesktopScaleFactor` registry key to `1` then it works again.

See https://serverfault.com/a/926838/448972

Comment: It seems this only works when I was already logged into PC2.

Comment: In the mean time I gave up. Because sometimes I've to restart PC2 and then I'm not logged in anymore. So I changed PC1 and PC2 to 150%. I'm getting used to it.

Comment: And 1 year later I got myself a pair of reading glasses :-|

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you are seeing is by design as Windows snaps scale factors to specific boundaries. This change was made at the end of 2018 to address underlying architectural issues. Scale factors in the latest Windows releases will snap to:

- 125%
- 150%
- 175%
- 200%
- 225%
- 250%
- 300%
- 350%
- 400%
- 450%
- 500%

Comment: It would be nice if you could add 133% (128/96=4/3) and 167% (160/96=5/3). This should be added not only to RDP it should be added to Windows 10 in general.

Answer (score 0):

Better solution is to edit your `.rdp` file in notepad and add this line anywhere. This will ignore both the local and remote default display scaling.

`desktopscalefactor:i:150`

This is documented on Microsoft website: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/rdp-files

You can choose any of the standard values: 100, 125, 150, 175, 200